# Google Places + Custom Places in Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-maps-markers, google-places-api, google-places

I'm currently working with Google Places, I've managed to get it working and it's all fine.

But I would like to be able to add some own places (let the user add places) and get 'em to show in a AutoComplete as well.

I looked over the Android Developer documentation, but can't seems to quite get it.

I've looked here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically but I still need to figure out how to add my own there as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at here : https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place...

As per the doc : "The newly-added place is available to your app after a short time, and is added to a moderation queue for possible addition to Google's Places database and Google Maps."

Comment: Oh okey, is there anyway to not add the place to Google Places, is it possible to just save it on the device. Like personal spots?

Comment: Is there a way to show all nearby places as markers on top of the Google Maps fragment?

Comment: @feeloor did you get the places(places only commercial like shops,groceries etc. for ref. look up app)?

Comment: @DevendraSingh Yes, I got all places but only when I enter a query, I want to show all places (stores and stuff) based on the camera bounds...

Comment: would you please share the code for getting the places. @feeloor I want to get only commercial places. my mail is droidwithme@gmail.com